# How to create a function with a variadic nest of `for` loops?

Tags: r, simulation, benchmarking, variadic-functions, variadic

### Requirement

```
for(i in 1:nsim)
    {
    for(fi in 1:length(FUNCTIONS))
        for(p1 in 1:length(param1))
            {
            for(p2 in 1:length(param2))
                {
                # ... [mathematically and so on]
                    
                    for(pN in length(paramN))
                        {
                                            
                        # do something here 
                        # with (i, fi, p1, p2, ... pN)
```

### Variadic Functions

Below is the stackoverflow definition.  To me, it represents the right amount of abstraction for a problem that can be solved using a function (generally procedural).

[image: Variadic]

### Motive: Benchmarking

So I was reviewing some of my code and options using `microbenchmark` based on some string-manipulation issues I have been having.  Going down the "rabbit hole", I reviewed the `microbenchmark` nano-timings and decided to see if they agreed with standard protocols.  The `microbenchmark` computations are relatively fast but the `print` and `summary` are slow, and I wanted some benchmark references so I wrote a function `ggg.benchmark` that lead to this output.

```
 time.is ...  [milliseconds (ms)] per call 

   idx                 expression        min lower-trecile     median upper-trecile        max relative.efficiency relative.factor Rank
2    2                 cpp_time() 0.00000035    0.00000057 0.00000065    0.00000074 0.00024615               52.90         0.47101    1
4    4           cpp_milli()/1000 0.00000040    0.00000060 0.00000069    0.00000080 0.00011427               50.00         0.50000    2
6    6        cpp_micro()/1000000 0.00000039    0.00000062 0.00000071    0.00000082 0.00011449               48.55         0.51449    3
5    5      cpp_now("milli")/1000 0.00000049    0.00000068 0.00000083    0.00000098 0.00010462               39.86         0.60145    4
7    7   cpp_now("micro")/1000000 0.00000049    0.00000068 0.00000084    0.00000100 0.00145392               39.13         0.60870    5
9    9 cpp_now("nano")/1000000000 0.00000050    0.00000069 0.00000084    0.00000100 0.00011454               39.13         0.60870    6
1    1     as.numeric(Sys.time()) 0.00000102    0.00000129 0.00000138    0.00000149 0.00000814                0.00         1.00000    7
8    8      cpp_nano()/1000000000 0.00000123    0.00000150 0.00000157    0.00000171 0.00000986              -13.77         1.13768    8
3    3                     .now() 0.00000130    0.00000160 0.00000169    0.00000186 0.00001599              -22.46         1.22464    9
11  11            time.now("cpp") 0.00000598    0.00000684 0.00000714    0.00000769 0.00141655             -417.39         5.17391   10
12  12           time.now("base") 0.00000599    0.00000686 0.00000716    0.00000770 0.00002909             -418.84         5.18841   11
10  10          time.now("first") 0.00000710    0.00000811 0.00000851    0.00000918 0.00128414             -516.67         6.16667   12
13  13               str.uniqid() 0.00017347    0.00017944 0.00018093    0.00018328 0.00289352           -13010.87       131.10870   13
```

My function behaved okay, but I added a caching algorithm to speed it up (see deviation of `max` from `median`), and ran the following:

```
> ggg.benchmark(mb.irony)
"milliseconds (ms)"
"mil"
"057b92b71ccfa406fc5d509f8b459d0e"


 time.is ...  [milliseconds (ms)] per call 

  idx             expression        min lower-trecile     median upper-trecile        max relative.efficiency relative.factor Rank
5   5  ggg.benchmark(mb.res)   53.57657      54.12626   54.17876      54.88361  218.67247               99.00         0.00998    1
4   4 summary(mb.res, "eps") 4475.81297    4488.51471 4489.81239    4523.80740 4533.85203               17.32         0.82683    2
1   1  summary(mb.res, "ns") 5413.74017    5424.41295 5430.13278    5456.10914 5600.27456                0.00         1.00000    3
2   2  summary(mb.res, "us") 5416.56048    5446.56292 5448.34089    5459.35504 5474.32398               -0.34         1.00335    4
3   3  summary(mb.res, "ms") 5418.25978    5449.20442 5462.20611    5493.99542 5578.11555               -0.59         1.00591    5
```

### Features of Benchmarking

- FUNCTIONS: Allow a `variable` number of expressions or functions to be evaluated
- PARAMS with OPTIONS: Allow a `variable` number of parameters with `variable` options on each to be considered
- Include a NULL function to above to capture system-performance norms
- For a given trial (nsim), randomize:  FUNCTION order, PARAM order
- For good data provenance, record `seeds` on randomness
- Allow for `Rprof` and/or `Rprofmem`
- Allow for comparison checks to the first FUNCTION (the `referent`) or a popular results (the `common`) to test accuracy at the same time

As I reviewed my needs for a benchmarking simulation, I came up with the following function parameters:

```
bm = function(..., list=NULL, 
                    setup = list("nsim" = 100, "compare.values" = TRUE, "identical.to" = "referent", "tol" = 0, "Rprof" = FALSE, "Rprofmem" = FALSE), 
                    params = list(
                            "str" = c("<i>hello friend</i>", " hello there world ", " ¡hola!, ¿que tal? "), 
                            "sep" = c(" ", "", "¿", "</i>")
                                )
                    )
    {
```

### Stumped:

In the above scenario, which was the basis for the design.  I have two parameters:  the string `str` and the separator `sep`.  I can pass into these a collection of parameter CHOICES or OPTIONS.  And on a given nest for loop, I will use one `str` CHOICE and one `sep` CHOICE to perform a call.  This implies that for a single `trial` as `nsim`, I have (`1+FUNCTIONS * length(param1) * length(param2)`) runs to perform.  For `nsim=1000` and 12 functions, 3 choices on param1, 4 choices on param2, I have the following:

```
Combinations to be performed:  1000×13×3×4  =  156,000
```

Maybe I can use a `while` loop.  I could capture all of the unique combinations as a string to later perform a single run ...

```
12-2-3 ... FUNCTION[12] ... PARAM1[2] ... PARAM2[3] ...
```

For a given `nsim` ... I will loop over all of the FUNCTIONS in a random order, all of each PARAM in a random order ...

Maybe if I wasn't thinking so linearly/procedurally, there would be another way (recursion).  Suggestions for other strategies are welcome, as I want to get it working.

Ultimately, however, this has been a lingering programming question I have had for a long time.  I have hard-coded many a for-loop with fixed loops and can't think how to make it variadic.  Any `C-based` solution is welcome:  `C++, C, javascript, R`

### QUESTION: How to create a `variadic` loop?

```
for(i in 1:nsim)
    {
    for(fi in 1:length(FUNCTIONS))
        for(p1 in 1:length(param1))
            {
            for(p2 in 1:length(param2))
                {
                # ... [mathematically and so on]
                    
                    for(pN in length(paramN))
                        {
                                            
                        # do something here 
                        # with (i, fi, p1, p2, ... pN)
```

Comment: You need a runtime-variable nesting of loops, so you need something like recursion or a manual stack to keep track of progress.  In C you might pass a `va_list` by reference down the recursion, and have each call read 2 args (a length and an array) with `va_arg`.  But even that basic thing, with the args always being the same type, no dynamic dispatching to handle functions vs. args to functions, you'd have to be able to read the same arg multiple times, each time through the loop in an outer level of nesting.  I don't think `va_arg` does that, so you'd have to build a custom data structure?

Comment: Thanks for the note.  It appears to INDEED be a challenging task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Java code that does what you want:

```
package p;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
// file:///D:/ray/dev/XPokerEval/XPokerEval.Pokersource/java/javadoc/org/pokersource/enum/NestedLoopEnumeration.html
public class NestedLoops implements Enumeration {
    NestedLoops(Integer[] indices,Integer[] limits) {
        this(indices,limits,null,null);
    }
    NestedLoops(Integer[] indices,Integer[] limits,Integer[] deltas) {
        this(indices,limits,deltas,null);
    }
    NestedLoops(Integer[] indices,Integer[] limits,Integer[] deltas,Integer[] initialValues) {
        this.indices=indices;
        this.limits=limits;
        if(deltas!=null) this.deltas=deltas;
        else {
            int n=indices.length;
            this.deltas=new Integer[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                this.deltas[i]=1;
        }
        if(initialValues!=null) this.initialValues=initialValues;
        else {
            int n=indices.length;
            this.initialValues=new Integer[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                this.initialValues[i]=0;
        }
    }
    void initialize() {
        iterations=0;
        count=0;
        int n=indices.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            indices[i]=initialValues[i];
    }
    boolean check() {
        for(int i=0;i<indices.length;i++)
            if(indices[i]>=limits[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
    Integer[] getNextState() {
        if(deltas==null) { // looks like we can remove this
            for(int i=indices.length-1;i>=0;indices[i--]=0)
                if(indices[i]+1<limits[i]) {
                    indices[i]++;
                    return indices;
                }
        } else {
            for(int i=indices.length-1;i>=0;indices[i--]=0)
                if(indices[i]+deltas[i]<limits[i]) {
                    indices[i]+=deltas[i];
                    return indices;
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return hasMoreElements;
    }
    @Override public Object nextElement() {
        if(hasMoreElements) { // this is why the enumeration copies the indices
            Object rc=indices;
            indices=getNextState();
            hasMoreElements=check();
            return rc;
        } else return null;
    }
    void loop(Consumer<Integer[]> consumer,int max) { // maybe should be run()?
        if(deltas!=null) for(int i=0;i<deltas.length;i++)
            if(deltas[i]<=0) {
                // System.out.println("delta["+i+"]="+deltas[i]+" is <=0!");
                throw new RuntimeException("delta["+i+"]="+deltas[i]+" is <=0!");
            }
        hasMoreElements=check();
        if(hasMoreElements) while(indices!=null) {
            if(iterations++>max) {
                System.out.println("iterations > "+max+" bailing2!");
                return;
            }
            // System.out.print("instance indices: "+Arrays.asList(indices));
            // System.out.print(", limits: "+Arrays.asList(limits));
            // System.out.print(", deltas: "+Arrays.asList(deltas));
            // System.out.println(", initial values:
            // "+Arrays.asList(initialValues));
            if(consumer!=null) consumer.accept(indices);
            indices=getNextState();
        }
        hasMoreElements=false;
    }
    int iterations;
    int count; // for user to count whatever he wants
    Integer[] indices;
    boolean hasMoreElements;
    final Integer[] limits;
    final Integer[] deltas;
    final Integer[] initialValues;
    static int xx=0; // yuck! - get rid of this!

}
```

// here is a test case:

```
package p;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import org.junit.Test;
public class NestedLoopsInstanceTestCase {
    final int[] ns=new int[1];
    Consumer<Integer[]> counter=x -> {
        //System.out.println(Arrays.asList(x)+" "+ns[0]);
        if(x!=null) ns[0]++;
    };
    @Test public void testGetNextState() {}
    @Test public void testIndices11WithAllOnes() {
        Integer[] limits= {1,1};
        Integer[] deltas= {1,1};
        Integer[] indices= {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits,deltas);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(1,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testIndices12WithAllOnes() {
        Integer[] limits=new Integer[] {1,2};
        Integer[] deltas= {1,1};
        Integer[] indices=new Integer[] {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits,deltas);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(2,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testIndices21WithAllOnes() {
        Integer[] limits=new Integer[] {2,1};
        Integer[] deltas= {1,1};
        Integer[] indices=new Integer[] {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits,deltas);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(2,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testIndices23WithAllOnes() {
        Integer[] limits=new Integer[] {2,3};
        Integer[] deltas= {1,1};
        Integer[] indices=new Integer[] {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits,deltas);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(6,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testLoop11() {
        Integer[] limits= {1,1};
        Integer[] indices= {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(1,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testLoop12() {
        Integer[] limits=new Integer[] {1,2};
        Integer[] indices=new Integer[] {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(2,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testLoop21() {
        Integer[] limits=new Integer[] {2,1};
        Integer[] indices=new Integer[] {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(2,ns[0]);
    }
    @Test public void testLoop23() {
        Integer[] limits=new Integer[] {2,3};
        Integer[] indices=new Integer[] {0,0};
        JNL nestedLoops=new JNL(indices,limits);
        nestedLoops.initialize();
        nestedLoops.loop(counter,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        assertEquals(6,ns[0]);
    }
}
```